# Where should i put createPool({ ... }) in mysql/mysql2?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, connection-pooling, mysql2

I am developing an e-commerce website and as of now I have these basic backend codes:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5429

const express = require ('express')
const server = express ()

const cors = require('cors')
server.use (cors ())

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
server.use (bodyParser.json ())
server.use (bodyParser.urlencoded ({ extended: true }))

server.listen (port, () => {
  console.log (`Server port listening to: ${ port }`)
})
```

Now I am having trouble where to put the
`const mysql = require ('mysql')` together with `mysql.createPool ({ ... })`.

1. Should i put them here before the `server.listen`? or
2. Should I go with this?

```
module.exports = class Database {
   connectWithPool () {}
}
```

and put is under here:

```
const Database = require ('./db.js')
const db = new Database ()
module.exports = class User {
   login (req, res) {
      ....
      db.connectWithPool ()
      ....
   }
}
```

and attach the `user.login` in route

```
const User = require ('user.js')
const user = new User ()
module.exports = class Routes {
  constructor (server) {
    this.server = server
  }
  routeUser () {
     this.server.post ('/api/user', user.login)
  }
}
```

3. Your suggestions. Because its not very clear to me how `createConnection` and `createPool` works internally.

P.S: disregard if there's an error to my codes. I just want to explain my own idea.